# pass ggplot color arguments to a script

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plotting function which I use to plot/save each column from a data frame. To pass `aes()` variables into ggplot I use the wonderful `aes_string` command as below.

```
plot <- function(df, column) {
  y <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x="x", y="y", color=column, label="vector")) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
  ggsave(y, file=paste("plots/plot_", column,".png",sep="")) 
}
```

I would now like to add a `scale_color_gradient2`  as in the [docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_gradient2.html), but I would like to set the `midpoint` to the mean of the column. Is there a similar way to pass this value into a function? I have tried the following which result in setting the graph points to grey.

```
z = y + scale_color_gradient2(midpoint = mean(column))
z = y + scale_color_gradient2(midpoint = mean(df$column))
```

I think I could get around this by precomputing the value and passing it to function but I wonder if there is a simple `aes_string()`-like way of doing this.

thanks,
zach cp

Comment: And what's wrong with your approach?

Comment: Try scale_color_gradient2(midpoint = colMeans(df[column]))